# matplotlib line graph from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create line graph in matplotlib from a dataframe with 10488 rows vs 3 columns. My dataframe appears like the following:

```
           col_A    col_B   col_C
target_id           
KYQ35740    22.67   19.7    26.0
KYQ35675    9.21    3.2 3.1
KYQ35736    73.93   42.8    24.6
KYQ35737    349.94  602.6   212.4
KYQ35685    16.10   19.5    29.1
```

Here, target id is the index. The trial I made was:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot') 
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("Data.txt", sep='\t', index_col=['target_id'])    
df.plot()
```

I get a bar graph with target Ids on x-axis and three colored bars representing each column. However, I need to produce the transpose of it. i.e col_A, col_B, col_C labels in x axis with plot marked with 10488 lines running through series. I don't require target_ids in legend.

I tried transposing the df with df.T followed by df.plot(). But the system hangs which I believe is due to 10488 labels needed to be put in legend ?!

Thanks in advance for your help.

AP

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how the resulting plot should look like. What does *"with plot marked with 10488 lines running through series"* mean? What I understand that you want to have the three categories col_A, .. col_C on the x axis. But how should points be represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the legend, you can use `legend=False`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = u"""target_id  col_A    col_B   col_C        
KYQ35740    22.67   19.7    26.0
KYQ35675    9.21    3.2 3.1
KYQ35736    73.93   42.8    24.6
KYQ35737    349.94  602.6   212.4
KYQ35685    16.10   19.5    29.1"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True,index_col=['target_id'])
df=df.T

df.plot(legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]